# LKM scheduling while atomic

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am developing a linux kernel module, which looks like this:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Me");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Something Something");

int checkSomething(void) {
    int someCpuFeature = 0;
    __asm__("mov $1, %eax");
    __asm__("cpuid");
    __asm__("mov %%ecx, %0" : "=r" (someCpuFeature));
    if (someCpuFeature & 32) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int __init init_module(void) {
    if (!checkSomething()) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Exiting\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Continuing\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Unloading Module\n");
}
```

And when i loaded it, i tried to see it's output from dmesg.
but instead of only printing Exiting/Continuing, it also printed a call trace,
and said **BUG: scheduling while atomic: insmod/24641/0x06100800**.
I searched this bug and found that it has some connection to the scheduler and sleeping at places you shouldn't sleep in, but this is the only functionality of the code,
So i think it has something to do with the cpuid instruction, but i don't know exactly what it is.
any ideas?

Comment: it's probably in your `someCondition` function that you do something you really shouldn't be doing.

Comment: someCondition is basically someCpuCondition & 32

Comment: can you *actually* give us the full code of a minimal example? Makes no sense to guess based on some excerpt of some code that might or might not contain the problematic part in your actual code.

Comment: edited, this is the entire code

Comment: it's not, there's none of the includes necessary to make this compile. please understand we're trying to help, but we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: added the includes

Comment: For starters, your asm sequence is wrong. Don't use separate asm statements. Use one asm block and use the appropriate clobbers for the regs you're using/trashing. If you look in the kernel source, it has many examples of correct asm usage.

Comment: Yeah, the inline asm is badly broken.  There are some resources at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info, and of course the relevant sections of the GCC manual need to read and digested thoroughly.  It is not trivial to write correct GCC extended asm; the compiler will usually not be able to tell you if it is wrong, and buggy code may even work for a while, so testing won't reliably catch bugs either.  You should not expect to be able to do it by guessing, even if you already know assembly language in general.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, considering the interrupts raised on my machine now, it would look like your assembler is incorrect.

Instead of writing this yourself, I'd recommend relying on the `cpuid` kernel module (and thus, reading `/dev/cpu/NUMBER/cpuid` after seeking to your level of interest), as that's future-proof external API. You can also look at `/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h`, and use kernel functions like `cpu_has` to detect your feature. Don't reinvent the wheel – querying details of a CPU on an SMP machine is bound to be painful, and the poor kernel developers had to go through the pain to make this work themselves.